# How can I distinguish if a request came from a Fetch API call, in a Node.js / Express / D3.js app?

Tags: node.js, express, d3.js

I have a web application built with Node.js and Express 4.x, where a typical page looks like this:

```html
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="d3-5.4.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(loadData); // When the page is fully loaded, call loadData()
    function loadData() {
        d3.json('/data/purchases').then(generateCharts);
    }
    function generateCharts(data) { }
</script>
...
```

It just calls [`d3.json()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch#json) to read data from the server, and then generates some charts with them.

The way `d3.json()` communicates with the server is with a GET request to the specified URL, /data/purchases in the example. If somebody types the same URL in the browser, they would obviously get the same response with the JSON data. And that's what I want to prevent.

Is there any way I can check whether a request came from a `d3.json()` call?

I thought of checking the `X-Requested-With` header with Express [`req.xhr`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.xhr) property, but it's set to false. Apparently `d3-fetch` doesn't use an XMLHttpRequest to load the data, they use the [new Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) instead.

I've also tried with [`req.is('application/json')`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.is)... but it returns null.

Anything else I can try?

<sub>PS: I already have a simple authorization system, which checks if the current user should have access to any requested URL, both for pages and API calls. But it requires some extra configuration data stored in my database, making the app slightly harder to maintain. So, given that we don't actually have any sensitive data, I thought I could drop the authorization checks for API calls, and instead allow them to be made only through `d3.json()` and not manually. I could instead allow them completely... I just *don't want to* :), which provides an opportunity to learn a bit more about Express and D3.js.</sub>

Comment: I would approach this question from a different angle. So basically you don't want to expose your API for everybody obviously. I would add a authentincation / authorization mechanism to your API, like exchanging tokens.

Comment: Thanks Sándor. I already have an authorization system for API calls... I actually wanted to remove it and do this other check instead :), if it's doable at all. I updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: Could you replace `d3.json` with your own Fetch call and just add a custom header if `d3.json` isn't actually doing anything special itself other than a GET request? Or use d3.request with a custom header and check that https://github.com/d3/d3-request/blob/master/README.md#request_header

Comment: Thanks TommyBs, apparently there's no need to replace it. d3.json allows to define custom headers too with the `init` parameter :D. I'll add a self answer with a small example once I get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d3.json()` [allows to pass init parameters](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch#json) to the underlying Fetch call. This can be used, [amongst other things](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#requestinit), to [define a custom header](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#typedefdef-headersinit):

```js
const initParams = {
    headers: new Headers({
        "MyVeryOwnHeader": "Hooray!"
    })
};

d3.json('/data/purchases', initParams).then(generateCharts);
```

Which can then be [checked server-side](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.get) in Express' routes.js file:

```js
if (req.get('MyVeryOwnHeader') === 'Hooray!') {
    // Valid API call made from d3.json, not by the user directly typing the URL
}
```

That's the basics; you can complicate it as much as you wish. For example, instead of a static value, you could generate a random token (or nonce) for each requested page, and store it in a session variable, to later check the value when you validate the next API call. The only problem would be users browsing with multiple tabs *simultaneously*: it could lead to race conditions where some pages would fail to load the necessary data.

And of course, if the user wants, they still can inspect the code, find out the last token, and then generate fake calls to the API including the custom header. This isn't intended to provide any security at all, only to discourage direct access to the data.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer by @AJPerez is certainly fine. But given that server code checking for the conventional header:

`X_REQUESTED_WITH: XMLHttpRequest`

has existed long before the `fetch` API was introduced to javascript, I would prefer to add that exact header to the `fetch` invocation, rather than inventing a new custom header. I.e.:

```
fetch(url, {headers: {'X_REQUESTED_WITH': 'XMLHttpRequest'}})
```